# Using ModelConverterBuilder

Tags: ckeditor5

How do I use the buildModelConverter as described here when developing my own ckeditor5 plugins: 
  https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_buildmodelconverter-ModelConverterBuilder.html

If I do a

```
npm install  @ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/buildmodelconverter
```

just gives me

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from
>   "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/buildmodelconverter" as it
>   does not contain a package.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the package first (the package is `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine`):

```
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine
```

Then, you need to use the name of the package (`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-foo`) + the path to the file (`src/foo/bar`) to import that thing:

```
import BuildModelConverter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/buildmodelconverter';
```

**BUT** That actual file does not exist for a long time and it's visible on https://docs.ckeditor.com by a mistake. I don't know how you found a link to it but that class was removed a half a year ago. Right now, the conversion API is organised around this class – [`editor.conversion`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html).

Comment: I found the page from google. This explains why I could not get it to work. I will look at editor.conversion instead.